Facing issue in playing audio chunks which are received from the backend server
My Backend is on Fast API and i am using StreamingResponse of Fast API to send the each audio chunk which i am receiving it from the AI Model
like this StreamingResponse(func(query_engine, query), media_type="audio/wan")
In the first code snippet i am able to hear the audio once all the chunks are received
In the second code snippet i am trying to play audio chunk by chunk but unable to do that
useEffect(() => {
    if (!finalSpeechToText) return;
    function getResult() {
      const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
      const data = {
        model: "aura-luna-en",
        text: finalSpeechToText,
      };
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/query/useChat", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })
        .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then((buffer) => {
          console.log("buffer", buffer);
          return audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer);
        })
        .then((audioData) => {
          console.log("audioData", audioData);
          const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
          source.buffer = audioData;
          source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
          source.start(0);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    getResult();
  }, [finalSpeechToText]);

Here i am get the response and able to listen the audio completely but it is not playing chunk by chunk
buffer  & audioData
useEffect(() => {
    if (!finalSpeechToText) return;
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    async function getResult() {
      const data = {
        model: "aura-luna-en",
        text: finalSpeechToText,
      };
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/query/useChat",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        }
      );
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
          return;
        }
        console.log("buffer", value);
        console.log("value.buffer", value.buffer);
        try {
          await new Promise((res) => {
            setTimeout(res, 5000);
          });
          const audioData = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(value.buffer);
          const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
          source.buffer = audioData;
          source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
          source.start(0);
        } catch (error: any) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      }
    }
    getResult();
  }, [finalSpeechToText]);

Here each chunk is getting printed after every 5 seconds and i am getting an error
Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data
the value of "value.buffer" is same as the audio Data in the above image

I want to play each audio chunk in the browser as soon as i get it;
